# Como enviar informaçoes por POST local para servidor externo?

Tags: php

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação que necessita estar em um servidor local e preciso enviar algumas informações para um servidor externo, de que maneira devo fazer?

Comment: Pode dar mais detalhes ?

Comment: Então amigo, a minha aplicação usa o Arduino e devido a isso o Arduino deve ficar conectado ao servidor, a aplicação possui um sistema de login, se o usuário esquecer a senha eu devo enviar um email com a nova senha, tentei enviar o email localmente com o PHPMailer mas não funcionou então minha ideia foi para mandar por POST as informações para que o servidor externo consiga enviar o email

Comment: Pode criar um Webservice no servidor externo e utilizar ele no Arduino.

Comment: Hmm, muito obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Para fazer um post a um servidor externo, use o curl:

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,            'http://www.exemplo.com.br');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,     http_build_query(array('login' => 'abc', 'senha' => '1234')));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,           true);

$consulta = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```